# Erlang : gen_server - reply to two clients

Tags: erlang, erlang-ports

As a newbie, writing a toy matching (trading) engine using gen_server.

Once a trade/match occurs there is need to notify both the clients.

Documentation says that :

> ```
> reply(Client, Reply) -> Result
> ```
>
> Types:
>
> ```
> Client - see below
> Reply = term()
> Result = term()
> ```
>
> This function can be used by a gen_server to explicitly send a reply
>   to a client that called `call/2,3` or `multi_call/2,3,4`, when the reply
>   cannot be defined in the return value of `Module:handle_call/3`.
>
> ***Client must be the From argument provided to the callback function.*** Reply is an arbitrary term, which will be given back to
>   the client as the return value of `call/2,3` or `multi_call/2,3,4`.
>
> The return value Result is not further defined, and should always be
>   ignored.

Given the above how is it possible to send notification to the other client.

SAMPLE SEQUENCE OF ACTIONS

```
   C1 -> Place order  IBM,BUY,100,10.55
   Server -> Ack C1 for order
   C2 -> Place order  IBM,SELL,100,10.55
      Server -> Ack C2 for order
             -> Trade notification to C2
             -> Trade notification to C1 %% Can I use gen_server:reply() 
                                         %% If yes - How ?
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can't. Your `ACK` is *already* a reply. And only single reply is acceptable by `gen_server:call` *contract*. I mean, `gen_server:call` will only wait for one reply.

Generally `gen_server:reply` can be implemented like

```
reply({Pid, Ref}, Result) ->
    Pid ! {Ref, Result}.
```

That means that if you try sending multiple replies, you just get some weired messages in the message box of the caller process.

## Proposal

Instead, I believe, you should send associate every trade with some reference, and send message to the caller with that reference `CX_Ref` during the ACK procedure. Then, when you have to send a notification, you just emit message `{C1_Ref, Payload}` to `C1` and `{C2_Ref, Payload}` to C2.

Also you may want to introduce some monitoring to handle broker crashes.

Comment: Thanx for clarification, would this mean that gen_server,  is not appropriate for a trading engine, it would make sense to use the other gen_*, which one is recommended.

Comment: @CSP, I'm not saying, that gen_server is inappropriate, I'm not saying it's best solution. I believe you can start with it, but you might want to change this decision later.